# How to get SVN revision number in Jenkins Workflow Plugin?

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I'm using Jenkins 1.596, Workflow 1.3, and Svn plugin 2.5.  I'm trying to get the svn revision number in my workflow script.

The section of my workflow script is:

```
node {
   checkout scm: [ $class: "SubversionSCM", locations: [[ remote:'https://secure3.svnrepository.com/somerepo/trunk', credentialsId: cid]] ]
   stage 'build'
   dir('trunk') {
      def revision = 'svn info'.execute().in.text.split('\n').find { it.startsWith('Revision') }.split(':')[1].trim()
      println revision
      def svnHome = tool 'Svn'
      sh "$svnHome/bin/svn info"
      def mvnHome = tool 'Maven'
      sh "export JAVA_HOME=/var/jenkins_home/java; $mvnHome/bin/mvn --version"
      sh "export JAVA_HOME=/var/jenkins_home/java; $mvnHome/bin/mvn clean deploy"
}
```

Here you see two attempts: the first prints "java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "svn": error=2, No such file or directory", and the second says "No tool named Svn found" (I also tried "Subversion").  Trying `def revision = System.getenv('SVN_REVISION')` prints "null".

Any idea how I might do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `No such file or directory` error means just what it says: Subversion is not installed on your build slave.

You seem to have gotten that, and tried to work around it by using `tool` to install Subversion. But the Jenkins Subversion plugin has no tool definition for Subversion; it always uses SVNKit, an in-process (Java) library. So this cannot work.

(By the way the Mercurial plugin always runs the `hg` executable, and the Git plugin can use either a `git` executable or the embedded JGit library. Both let you define tool installations, but do *not* define special (automatic) installers, so they would not be of much help for this kind of situation. You would do as well running `sh 'sudo apt-get install subversion'`.)

Assuming you install Subversion so that `svn` is in your `$PATH`, the next issue is that using `String.execute()` from the GDK will not generally work in a Workflow either. That is because the flow script is run inside the Jenkins master process, not on the slave. You must use the `sh` step (or `bat` on a Windows slave) to run external commands. As to getting output back from them, [JENKINS-26133](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26133) describes the current idiom.

`String.find` from the JDK will not currently work: [JENKINS-26481](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481). Use Java Platform methods instead, or just anything not taking a closure.

For reasons similar to why `String.execute()` is inappropriate, `System.getenv` will not work to get “environment variables” defined for the workflow build: this will only load environment variables set on the Jenkins master process, fixed at Jenkins startup time. The variables you are thinking of are set only on forked processes (`sh`/`bat`); or you can access them from Groovy using `env.VARIABLE` syntax.

What you really wanted to begin with was direct access to `SVN_REVISION` without having to run `svn info` yourself. This is tracked as [JENKINS-26100](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26100).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!  So I'm understanding that there's no way to do it right now?  If not, I can just use a timestamp.

Comment: You can run `svn info` from a `sh` step, so long as Subversion is installed on the slave.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it using the variables for each SVN module. See the answers below
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24956967/5842403
Basically you use the $SVN_REVISION_x variable where "x" is a counter of the svn URL module. You can echo that variable and put in a file as an artifact.

Answer (score 0):

Since I found a nice script in the internet (I do not remember where) and we use groovy scripting, I wanted to share this solution which worked for me very well:

```
def url = "ENTER HERE YOUR SVN URL"
def SVN_REVISION = "svn info --show-item last-changed-revision $url".execute().text

echo "$SVN_REVISION" /*should work now*/
```

Sorry for exhuming this thread, but I hope this will work for some people.

Do not forget to use double quotation marks when using these variables.
This was kinda difficult to find out for me. :-/

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32744.

I had the same issue (environment variable isn't loaded). 
You can get the revision number from a file named "revision.txt" in the path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\${pipelineTaskName}\builds\${buildNumber}".