# Get SVN Revision in jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins

I've some trouble passing retrieving the SubVersion Revision to the jenkins pipeline..

I've configured a string parameter called Version where I type the first 3 pieces of the version (ex 1.12.0) I wish to pass to the Jenkins version plugin that value with the SVN revision

[image]

I've googled around and tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191399/how-to-get-svn-revision-number-in-jenkins-workflow-plugin) approach but with no luck

Any suggestion ? I've tried as well to retrieve it from groovy script but with no luck

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136459/how-to-get-svn-version-number-from-checkout-for-use-in-dsl/44224326#44224326

Answer (score 0):

In pipeline code you can access the SubvesionSCM and get the revision number from a file. See [How to get svn version number from checkout for use in dsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136459/how-to-get-svn-version-number-from-checkout-for-use-in-dsl/44224326#44224326)