# How to get svn version number from checkout for use in dsl

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I created a pipeline job and would like to get the svn version number to enable further downstream processing in a call to a shell script.  I am using a pipeline script similar to the following:

```
node {
   // Mark the code checkout 'stage'....
   stage 'Checkout'

   // Get some code from a SVM repository
   checkout(
       [
           $class: 'SubversionSCM', 
           additionalCredentials: [], 
           excludedCommitMessages: '', 
           excludedRegions: '', 
           excludedRevprop: '', 
           excludedUsers: '', 
           filterChangelog: false, 
           ignoreDirPropChanges: false, 
           includedRegions: '', 
           locations: [
               [
                   ...
                ]
            ], 
            workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateUpdater']
        ]
    )
    def svnversionnumber=${SVN_VERSION}



   sh "/.../someshellscript ${svnversionnumber};"
}
```

Is there documentation on the checkout function available?  Is it possible to get hold of the svn revision number?  I can see that the revision is output to the log.

Comment: Which version exactly are you trying to get ? SVN Server version ? Client version ? Code version ?

Comment: the code revision number @Pom12

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue, but you can solve it by using the map that is returned from calling [SCM checkout](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/).  It contains a value for SVN_REVISION.

```
// Get some code from a SVM repository
def scmVars = checkout(
  ...
)

def svnversionnumber = scmVars.SVN_REVISION
```

Comment: Can I get the SVN revision number without getting / download the code?

Comment: Does this assignment also work in Declarative syntax (under a `pipeline`, and not `node`)? I kept getting parsing errors on `def`

Comment: Never mind! I needed to put things in a `script { .. }` block to be able to "escape" to scripted pipeline syntax ([doc](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script))... Also, note that as @Mikhail 's answer below elaborated, if you're checking out from multiple URLs, the revision number accessor will be number suffixed.

Comment: Is this still working? My console displays one revision number and the SVN_REVISION  don't match.


def checkoutResults  = checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', ... )
                echo "Full checkoutResults: " + checkoutResults
                def versionNumber = checkoutResults.SVN_REVISION
                echo manager.build.getDisplayName() + " " + versionNumber


checkout log ex:
Updating https://myrepo/path at revision '2019-04-30T11:06:10.962 -0400'
Using sole credentials ... in realm ‘<https://myrepo:443> VisualSVN Server’
At revision 25043 <this is not matching versionNumber

Comment: @AlexWeitz I did eventually get this to work for me by changing the syntax to this...

def checkoutResults  = checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM' ...snip...)
manager.build.setDisplayName(manager.build.getDisplayName() + " " + checkoutResults['SVN_REVISION'])

Comment: Please note that this information is at present (June 2020) not 100% reliable. In our setup we see cases where the SVN_REVISION reported is not the actual revision that was checked out. This is in combination with svn:externals and shared libraries. It might be related to https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45489.

Answer (score 5):

In Groovy pipeline script it's possible to get results of `checkout scm` command into TreeMap variable and then get what you need:

```
def checkoutResults = checkout([
            poll: false, 
            scm: [
                $class: 'SubversionSCM', 
                ...
            ]
        ])
echo 'checkout results' + checkoutResults.toString()
echo 'checkout revision' + checkoutResults['SVN_REVISION']
echo 'checkout revision' + checkoutResults['SVN_REVISION_1']
echo 'checkout revision' + checkoutResults['SVN_REVISION_2']
```

Answer (score 3):

I ended up invoking a shell to get the svn revision number as follows

```
def svnVersionNumber = sh(
    script: "svn info --show-item last-changed-revision $url",
    returnStdout: true
)
```

This was the only way I could get it to work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

this code work for me in jenkins pipeline:

```
String url = 'svn+ssh:...'
SVN_REVISION_IN = sh returnStdout: true, script: 'svn info --show-item last-changed-revision ' + url
currentBuild.displayName = "Rev: ${SVN_REVISION_IN}"
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a file called revision.txt in the build dir. The [SubversionSCM](https://github.com/jenkinsci/subversion-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/scm/SubversionSCM.java) provides methods to read this file.

```groovy
//Here remote returns url@revision but the revision part is across the entire repo 
//We will use the url part to get the revision for our branch

def remote = scm.locations.first().remote
def url = remote.split('@').first()

//The revision file has the revision for our branch. Parse returns a map.
def revmap = scm.parseRevisionFile(currentBuild.rawBuild)
revmap[url]
```

The scm variable is available on Jenkinsfiles. If you are not using a Jenkinsfile you should be able to create the scm object and pass it into the checkout method.

Comment: org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method hudson.scm.SubversionSCM getLocations :(

Comment: Just approve it under Manage Jenkins » In-process Script Approval

Answer (score -1):

I think one of the best choice can be use a simple little "groovy console script" to get the revision number then put into a Jenkins variable..

Something like this to give you an idea:
[Link](http://buildlackey.com/a-groovy-script-to-determine-the-svn-revision-number-of-your-source-base/)

Take also a look at this question: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945047/obtain-subversion-revision-from-previous-jenkins-build/24956967#24956967)

Comment: @ivoryJavaBoy unfortunately your first link provided is faulty.  Searched on google but similar links are not resolvable.  The second link I have seen but attempting to use that variable did not provide a solution. It always resolves to null

Comment: sweetfeet i corrected the first link... about the variable i did not try it but knowing there are a lot of unknown Jenkins variable, i supposed it worked. By the way as i told you.. the groovy one it's just an example, i would do a groovy simple script the perform and svn info on the repo to get the repository...quick and easy...

Comment: Thanks @ivoruJavaBoy

Comment: Unfortunately one falls foul of security restrictions. Unable to use "".execute() as this is a static method.  Cant use the ProcessBuilder constructor to get a process because your are not allowed to use the constructor with the list argument.  Will have no hair left soon.