# Get SVN revision in declarative jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, svn, revision, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a simple question: How can I get the svn revision in a [declarative jenkins pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline). Similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136459/how-to-get-svn-version-number-from-checkout-for-use-in-dsl/44224326#44224326).

What I found out so far:

When you use a **Freestyle job**, simply use

```
${SVN_REVISION}
```

When you use a **Scripted Pipeline**, use the following command:

```
def scmVars = checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM',...])
svnRevision = scmVars.SVN_REVISION
```

[checkout syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/#pipeline-scm-step)

But how do I get the SVN Revision in a **Declarative Pipeline**? `SVN_REVISION` is not defined, `def` is not allowed in declarative pipelines and `checkout scm` is only for multibranch pipelines.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the quick answer. I found another solution with `script`.
I know it is not the best solution, but it works.

```
script {
    def scmVars = checkout ([$class: 'SubversionSCM',...])
    svnRevision = scmVars.SVN_REVISION
}
```

Answer (score 2):

according to here https://qa.nuxeo.org/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals

> The following variables are currently unavailable inside a Pipeline
>   script:
>
> SCM-specific variables such as SVN_REVISION

so better try to find the way (the best one will be shell script) to get revision after checking out and then use it for your needs.