Jenkins: get svn revision from checkout in pipeline
I am trying to get the SVN revision which is checked out, so that I can display it as part of the build name and store it with the artifact. I am using a declarative pipeline.
My google research pointed me to snippets along the lines of i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50352255/258418:
script {
    def scm = checkout ([$class: 'SubversionSCM',...])
    svnRevision = scm.SVN_REVISION
}

Unfortunately it looks like checkout returns an empty object. Not being familiar with groovey, I tried to inspect the scmVars object as follows and only got empty results:
scm.properties.each { println "$it.key -> $it.value" }  // nothing printed
println scm                                             // "{}"
println scm.SVN_REVISION                                // "null"
println scm.toString()                                  // "[:]"

My research also indicated that a while back environment variables where injected, but this seems to no longer be the case (https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-54492).
The version of the SVN plugin is 1281.vc8837f91a_07a_.
